# total salary from salary and commission

Tags: sql

```
Employee (emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_salary, emp_comm, emp_salary, emp_comm)
```

Here, every employee has a salary but some have commission (other wise its `NULL`).

Need to Write a query in sql that calculates the total salary for all employees(add the salary and commission) where some employees don't get a commission (commission is `NULL` here).

I tried

```
SELECT emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_salary, emp_comm, emp_salary+emp_comm "Total Salary"
FROM employee;
```

It gives a number who has salary and commission, but got `NULL` for all other who has commission as `NULL` not any number.

I got..

```
(EMP_FNAME,EMP_LNAME,EMP_SALARY,EMP_COMM,"Total_Salary)
('Steve','Allen',1600,300,1900)
('Sue','Miller',1300,null,null)
```

But want `EMP_Salary` as Total salary if `EMP_Comm` is `NULL`.

Comment: if this is sql server, check out the `ISNULL` function.

Comment: You need to replace the null value with a 0 before you do the calculation, the function(s) that does this depends on what database you use. It could be `isnull, ifnull, coalesce` or something similar.

Comment: thanks. coalesce worked.

Answer (score 4):

`null` is unknown so 1 + unkownn = unknown (not 1).

You have to replace the null with a zero. One way is the `coalesce` function:

```
select emp_fname,
       emp_lname,
       emp_salary,
       emp_comm,
       emp_salary + coalesce(emp_comm, 0) as total_salary
  from employee
```

`coalesce` can be used to specify multiple substitutions for a null value (in order of preference, where if the 2nd is also null, it tries the 3rd, then the 4th, etc. until a not null value is reached) and works in most databases.

If you want to replace the null with one value and always one value that is normally achieved by other functions but it depends on the database. `nvl` would be used in Oracle, `isnull` would be used in sql server, `ifnull` in mysql. Refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: thanks.. just for knowing, is it possible to use  union as relational set operator between two query to get the same result.

Comment: `union` horizontally combines the result set of 2 or more queries, which doesn't apply to this situation.